# firestore add/append data to field without overwrite using update with variables

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to add new medication that contains "medc name, medc dose, medc dur"
I used update but the problem is the first argument. Im giving it a non-existing name so it adds it to the existing medications
[image: here's a snippet from my code]

[image: here's a snippet I need to add medication like "Panadol"]

the right syntax is "medication.avamys : medArr 'that contains the dose and dur'"
but this part "medication.avamys" is varying
so what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the JavaScript syntax to use an expression as the property of an object.

```
...update({
    ["medication."+medcName]: medArr
})
```

Note the expression is in square brackets, and becomes the name of the field written to the document.

Note also that you are not required to build the object within the call to `update()`.  You can build the object in a different statement, and pass it to `update()`.  This is effectively the same thing, and probably more readable if you have lots of properties to assign:

```
const data = {}
data["medication."+medcName] = medArr
...update(data)
```

Comment: If you found it helpful, it's courtesy on Stack Overflow to upvote the answer and mark it as correct.